# How to count certain rows in a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently have a table that looks like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFP6Q.png

This is a comment system. the column id gives the comment an ID. the server_id is the ID for the section the comment was posted on. The user_id is the ID for the person who posted it. And lastly, the comment is the comment itself. Here is how I created the comment:

http://pastebin.com/VHUDW6Dm

What I want to do is create a variable, $commentcount, that will count how many comments there are for a server and be able to display them on a page. If someone could direct me to a function that can help me with this or actually create the code here, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us your attempt. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include the contents hidden behind the links in your question. It should include all relevant info. If your problem is caused by something not written here or needs such info to be discovered, your question is not well written. The link may break in the future and this question would lack important information. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very rough draft for you would be to iterate a count.

```
 $q = mysql_query("MYSQL QUERY TO GET ALL THE COMMENTS FOR THE USER");

 $count = 1; // Start the count, preferrably at 1

 while ($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $count++; //iterate the count
 }

 echo $count; // Echo's the count;
```

Comment: This is going to be very slow on large result sets. All the records need to be read from database, which has large overhead. When the record are needed themselves, this is the best approach, but when only the count is needed, COUNT() aggregate function is waaay better as the computation is done in the database server (allowing optimization) and only the results are transferred to the application.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the number of comments per server, you can use the SQL GROUP BY clause to aggregate the resulting rows by the unique server_id.

```
SELECT server_id, COUNT(id) FROM comments GROUP BY server_id;
```

This will return the count for each server_id group. If you are only displaying this for a single server_id at a time, you can simply use

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM comments WHERE server_id = <your server id>;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

use following mysql query

> select count(*) as count_comment from comments;